# Search Results caching

Tags: sxa, razor

I cloned Search Results Component and when I edit any thing in cshtml inside else scope

```
<div @Html.Sxa().Component(Model.Rendering.RenderingCssClass ?? "search-results testShaimaa", Model.Attributes) data-class-variant="@variantClass" data-properties='@Model.JsonDataProperties'>

@if (WebUtil.GetQueryString(Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search.Constants.CreativeExchangeExport) != "true")
{
    <div class="component-content">
        @Model.MessageIsEmpty
        <div class="no-results" style="display: @Model.StyleDisplay">
            @Html.Sxa().Field("ResultsNotFoundText", Model.DataSourceItem, !Model.IsControlEditable)
            @Html.Sxa().Field("Text", Model.Item, !Model.IsControlEditable)
        </div>
        <div class="progress"></div>
    </div>
}
else
{
<div>ssss</div>
<div>ssss</div>
    <ul class="search-result-list testShaimaa">
        <li>

            @foreach (BaseVariantField variantField in Model.VariantFields)
            {
                @Html.RenderingVariants().RenderVariant(variantField, Model.PageItem, true, Model)

            }
        </li>
    </ul>

}
```

does not reflect in the page but when I edit before If it reflects in the page so I am sure that this  the correct cshtml file for this cloned search result rendering,
I think that caching but I changed variant and cloned another one.

Any Ideas Why this happens and how my changes reflects in the page ??

Answer (score 1):

Your "if" statement mentions Creative Exchange:

`if (WebUtil.GetQueryString(Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search.Constants.CreativeExchangeExport) != "true")`

This tells me that the `else` part will be executed when the Creative Exchange parameter is in the querystring. That is why you will never see that part in the actual website - you'll always get the first (if) part.

More information on Creative Exchange on the official docs: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/working-with-creative-exchange.html

Comment: So how can the Html inside the else part be modified?

Answer (score 0):

The class "search-results testShaimaa" you are using in this line :

```
<div @Html.Sxa().Component(Model.Rendering.RenderingCssClass ?? "search-results testShaimaa", Model.Attributes) data-class-variant="@variantClass" data-properties='@Model.JsonDataProperties'>
```

is the same *Rendering css class* field added to your cloned view rendering? also cross the the path for the view file in the field: *Rendering view path - e.g. ~/Views/Title/Title.cshtml [shared]:* Under Experience Accelerator section